# Connecting Marklogic Database

Tags: jmeter, database-connection, marklogic

I'm tryng to connect jmeter and marklogic using postgresql-42.1.4.jar or mljdbc-42.1.4.jar. 
My app-servers:

[image]

My Configuration of JDBC:

[image]

And i received the error:  "Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection attempt failed.)"

What i do wrong? help?

Comment: Are you using the instructions at https://developer.marklogic.com/code/jdbc/ ?

Comment: Yes, I'm tryng to connect using the tutorial but i receive the same error every time :"Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The connection attempt failed.)"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember the default postgresql validation query used to validate the JDBC connection is not a valid SQL statement for MarkLogic. JMeter uses apache commons dbcp for its connection pooling which in turn uses a validation query to validate the connections.

Not sure what the query is (I'm sure this is somewhere in the source code) but you need to change that.

Go to "JDBC Connection Configuration" and set "Validation Query" to `select 1`.

For reference the complete exception message is:

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory
>   (isValid() returned false)

Comment: Thank you,
I change my "Validation Query" to select 1, and I received the same error.

Comment: I don't know then. You could set logging level to debug and to better understand whats wrong.